# what is the difference between keep // in mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //mysql_select_db("users")

Tags: php

What is the difference between keeping // in

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//mysql_select_db("users")

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("users")
```

Comment: The // begin a comment. So, the first line connect to the db without choosing a default db for query. The second one choose a db for query. In the first case you will be forced to use on sql mydb.table, on second case you can use select * from mytable

Answer (score 0):

AS in your question

`mysql_connect("localhost","root","");` works as a connection to mysql and `//mysql_select_db("users")` work as a comment in your code.

`mysql_connect("localhost","root","");` works as a connection to mysql and

`mysql_select_db("users");` works as a select database from mysql to perform table/database operations.